# Ownership issue with Shell Runner

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, runner

I'm trying to setup a pipeline on my django project with a shell runner.

I have 2 jobs :

- one to build my image
- one to run the tests.

The first build succeeded but when during my second job I have an **ownership** issue on my jobs folder :

```
warning: failed to remove api/__pycache__/resolvers.cpython-37.pyc
```

Here is my gitlab runner config :

```
[[runners]]
  name = "Shell Runner"
  url = "https://gitlab.com"
  token = "<my-token>"
  executor = "shell"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
```

Is there a way to have separate jobs for build and test without this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after struggling with this I finally found a solution.

When python install modules in `__pycache__` the owner is `root` so the runner can not delete those files between each jobs.

To fix this I added `ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1` in my `Dockerfile` to prevent the creation of `__pycache__` files.